# How does the social meta tags work in Pico CMS 2.0?

Tags: twig

I saw that there are some code to manage social info (Facebook, etc.) within Pico CMS 2.0, but I cannot find any example. The code example has this in the twig file :

```
{% for social in pages._meta.meta.social %}
    <a href="{{ social.url }}" title="{{ social.title }}" role="button">
        <span class="icon-{{ social.icon }}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">{{ social.title }}</span>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

But it is not clear where the meta info must go. I saw an example with the following code, in a separate file call `_meta.md`, but it does not seem to work:

```
---
social:
  - title: Visit us on Facebook
    url: https://example.com/sallysflowers
    icon: facebook
  - title: Check us out on Twitter
    url: https://example.com/sallyflora
    icon: twitter
  - title: Contact us by Email!
    url: mailto:sallysflowershop@example.com
    icon: mail
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, it is only a copy/paste issue. PicoCMS is very picky about the number of spaces before the meta sub-items.

There needs to be four spaces before the dashes sub-items, and six space before the other sub-items. Any other value seems to simply make the social items not work. So the answer would be:

```
---
social:
    - title: Visit us on Facebook
      url: https://example.com/sallysflowers
      icon: facebook
    - title: Check us out on Twitter
      url: https://example.com/sallyflora
      icon: twitter
    - title: Contact us by Email!
      url: mailto:sallysflowershop@example.com
      icon: mail
---
```

Note that social icons are made using Fontello, and icon calls are defined in the `themes/default/css/fontello.css` which also uses `themes/default/icon/*` files.